# Leaflet.js path clicking on mobile

Tags: javascript, mapping, leaflet

I'm using leaflet in a PhoneGap project, with offline map tiles.  Everything technically works just fine.  However I'm finding that it is very hard to get the click event to fire on the paths, requiring the user to do a lot of frustrating tapping over and over in the same spot until it finally fires.

These aren't teeny tiny paths.  Think bike paths in a mid-sized city, spiderwebbed everywhere.

Is this just something I have to live with with leaflet, or are there some tips and tricks to make the maps more touch friendly?

EDIT: And if not: is there a better way to do PhoneGap / Web based cached maps with better touch responsiveness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, about the only solution I've come up with on this one was to simply make the lines thicker.  I chose a weight of "8" which seems to work slightly better for my fat, sausage like fingers on my iPhone, but you'll want to test different devices and see what works for you.

You might also want to adjust your opacity too, as the larger lines will overlap more and might not look the greatest in congested path areas.

Answer (score 0):

As Leaflet.js [claims](http://leafletjs.com/features.html) to already have been mobile-optimized with the following thing

- Multi-touch zoom (iOS, Android 4+, Win8)
- Double tap zoom
- Various events: click (tap), mouseover, contextmenu, etc
- Tap delay elimination on mobile devices

I do not think there is much you can do to improve the touch-friendliness of it, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I'm up a creek without a paddle, but you never know when you are missing that "make_it_work" option. Perhaps you have a suggestion on my edit above?

Comment: @DaveSanders: I am wrong man to answer that question really as I lack the experience necessary. Also it is out of scope for this question and would require much more specification about what is needed actually and is unanswerable with that few information. Sorry mate :(